# Nest posts from loop under different parents in Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

My goal is to have posts from coming from a WordPress loop to be nested inside different parent divs like so

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="post">Post 1</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="upper">Post 2</div>
    <div class="lower">Post 3</div>
</div>
```

At the moment, I'm manually counting the posts in the loop and I'm displaying them according to the index.

```
$cat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category_id,'posts_per_page' => '3', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
$count = 0;
while($cat_query->have_posts()) : 
    $cat_query->the_post(); $count++; ?>

        <?php if($count == 1) : ?>
            <div class="left"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php elseif($count == 2 || $count == 3) : ?>
            <div class="right"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

But this is returning the following HTML tags

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="post">Post 1</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    Post 2
</div>
<div class="right">
    Post 3
</div>
```

Comment: Why use a loop for this in the first place, when you want to output a fixed number of three posts only? `<div class="left"><?php $cat_query->the_post(); the_title(); ?></div> <div class="right"><div class="upper"><?php $cat_query->the_post(); the_title(); ?></div> <div class="lower"><?php $cat_query->the_post(); the_title(); ?></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure about the logic for the `upper/lower` class that you used in the example but here is the code with explanation comments for left/right div.

```
$cat_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat'            => $category_id,
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
    )
);

// Check if have posts.
if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
    // Since we have post start with the left div
    // But don't repeat it inside the loop since we just need 1 left div.
    echo '<div class="left">';

    // Set first post flag true by default if post count is more than 1
    // It will be changed to false inside the while loop.
    $first = true;
    $first = $cat_query->post_count > 1 ? true : false;

    // Loop through posts.
    while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
        // Setup post.
        $cat_query->the_post();

        // Print the post title with before and after the markup.
        the_title( '<div class="post">', '</div>' );

        /**
         * Note: I am not sure what is the your logic for upper/lower class
         * that you have shown in the example but you'll have to apply
         * that logic on your own since you didn't explain it on 
         * the original question.
         */

        // If the first post then set it to false for the next iteration.
        if ( $first ) {
            $first = false;
            // Since it's the first post and we don't need any other
            // posts on left div. we'll close the left div and will start
            // the right div.
            // it will be printed only once since the first will not be true again.
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="right">';
        }
    }

    // Close the left div, which will become the closing div of the right in the while loop.
    echo '</div>';
}
```